# Windows 10 Kill EDB Postgres 8080 server

Tags: windows, postgresql, jenkins, enterprisedb

I want to kill and remove the software that uses the 8080 port that EDB Postgres localhost server so I can use the port for Jenkins.

Using tasklist it tells me the port which is processing, fine for kill the process, but where can I delete uninstall the software.

Comment: Postgres does not use Port 8080. By default it uses 5432.

Comment: EDB does use 8080

Comment: Maybe some tool from EDB, but most probably not the database server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tasklist is good but you can also use netstat -ano to find the port if you didn't find the process but in taskmanager in windows 10 there is a services tab with a PID column. Just click the column and find the PID. Then right click it and hit properties to find the path of the software. Kill the process and remove the software. Restart and see if it works.

Answer (score 13):

Just find the server named "PEM HTTPD" and turn it off.Also you can change its start mode to manual.

Answer (score 3):

You need to stop the service manually in the "Services" setting in Control Panel on Windows 10, you need to find: PEM HTTPD and Postgres Enterprise Manager - pemAgent. You will select each one and go to properties and set it to "Manual" because by default is set to "Automatic", and then and stop the service. Consequently you'll have port 8080 free.

Answer (score 0):

To stop or "kill" a running EDB Postgres server process on Windows 10, you can follow these steps:

1. **Identify the Process:**

   - Open a Command Prompt with administrative privileges. To do this, search for "Command Prompt" in the Windows Start menu, right-click on it, and select "Run as administrator."
   - Run the following command to list all the processes listening on port 8080:

     ```bash
     netstat -ano | findstr :8080
     ```
   - Note the PID (Process Identifier) of the process using port 8080.
2. **Terminate the Process:**

   - Once you have the PID of the process, you can terminate it using the `taskkill` command. Replace `<PID>` with the actual PID number from step 1.

     ```bash
     taskkill /F /PID <PID>
     ```
   - The `/F` flag forces the termination of the process, and the `/PID` flag specifies the process identifier.

Answer (score 0):

cmd -> service.msc -> find "postgresql-x64 ..." -> right click -> pause